# UITableViewCell Containing A Custom View with UICollectionView in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multidimensional-array, uicollectionview

I have a `CUSTOMVIEW` with a xib and it the view contains a `UICollectionView` in it.
then i add that custom view inside a `UITableViewCell` which is in a `UIViewController`.
From that `UiviewController` i create an array of arrays with different length to fill `UICollectionViewCell`. But im not having the desired result.
`UITableView` after third array it repeats the 3 first arrays here is a sample of arrays in `UIViewControllers viewDidLoad`:

```
array1= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:zeroItem, seventhItem, nil];
array2= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:thirdItem,forthItem,nil];
array3= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fifthItem,sixthItem, nil];
array4= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:eighthItem,seventhItem, nil];
array5= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:forthItem,zeroItem, nil];
```

And i fill main array in lazy instantiation:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)arrayStack
{
    if (!_arrayStack) {
        _arrayStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [_arrayStack addObject:array1];
         [_arrayStack addObject:array2];
         [_arrayStack addObject:array3];
         [_arrayStack addObject:array4];
         [_arrayStack addObject:array5];        
    }
    return _arrayStack;
}
```

And here is the dataSource of the `UITableView` where i fill the `UICollectionViewCell` with arrays:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.arrayStack count];
}

- (FFStackCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FFStackCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FFStackCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.THECUSTOMVIEW.stackOfVideos = self.arrayStack[indexPath.row];
    cell.theTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stack %ld",(long)indexPath.row+1];

    return cell;
}
```

The Problem here is that after array3 the arrays repeat themselves and array4 and array5 do not appear.
Am I mixing the delegate of the `UITableView` which is in `UIViewController` and `UICollectionView` which is in `CUSTOMVIEW` i am creating.
So please give me some suggestion.
Thanks in advance.